# JavaScript - Equivalent of PHP Class self::

Tags: javascript, php

So I've been searching on this because it's giving me a headache not being able to achieve this... And seems like there is no solution the way I expected to be.

Let's assume we have a sample `PHP` class:

```
<?php 

class SampleClass {

    function doA() {
        echo 'Hello world';
    }

    function doB() {

        $sampleArray = ['Hey', 'You'];

        foreach( $sampleArray as $key => $value ) {

            self::doA();

        }

    }

}

?>
```

This code will echo `Hello World` two times because of the foreach loop. And thats good.

Now I have this `script`:

```
function SectionHandler($appWrap) {

 this.appWrap = $appWrap;

 this.loading = function() {
    this.appWrap.addClass('section-loading').html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin'></i>");
 }

 this.setError = function($info) {
    this.appWrap.addClass('section-error').html($info);
 }

 this.load = function($section) {

  var $fileCheck = $.get($section).success(function(){
    self.loading();
    self.load($section);
  }).fail(function(){
    self.setError('No se pudo cargar los datos especificados desde ' + $section + ' ;');
  });

 }

}
```

I believe that `this.loading()` is no longer pointing to the main function because of the `$.get().success()` function. I do not know the real reason.

The problem is that none of `this.loading(), this.load(), this.setError()` is working.

So, how I do to point to the main function like I were using `PHP self::` function.?

#### -- EDIT --

As @Eclecticist pointed out the line `this.load($section);` will execute untill it fails or gets an error, I change the whole check to this:

```
var $fileCheck = $.get($section).done(function(response){
 self.appWrap.html(response);
}).fail(function(){
 self.setError('No se pudo cargar los datos especificados desde ' + $section);
});
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.javascriptkata.com/2007/05/14/how-to-use-the-self-with-object-oriented-javascript-and-closures/

Comment: @Mark I've been thinking so much about this that I could not guess that one... Now I feel dumb hehe... Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function SectionHandler($appWrap) {
    var that = this;

    this.appWrap = $appWrap;
    this.loading = function() {
        that.appWrap.addClass('section-loading').html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin'></i>");
    }

    this.setError = function($info) {
        that.appWrap.addClass('section-error').html($info);
    }

    this.load = function($section) {
        var $fileCheck = $.get($section).success(function(){
            that.loading();
            that.load($section);
        }).fail(function(){
            that.setError('No se pudo cargar los datos especificados desde /[ ' + $section + ' ]\ ;');
        });
    }    
}
```

The problem is the value of `this` changes once you're inside of a function.  You can address it by declaring a variable within your main function, `that`, and reference it later on.

--edit--

I want to note that the line `that.load($section);` will recursively call `SectionHandler.load()` until the AJAX request either fails, or until you get a `stackoverflow` error.

And yes, I've been hoping something came up where I could reference that error :)

Comment: You can just remove that line.  As it's written right now, I see no purpose in calling `$.get()` on the same URL over and over.

Answer (score 1):

You have the idea right, but the context of `this` *can* change within the scope of another function (and it does in the context of jQuery callbacks), so if you want to ensure that `this.loading()` is always what you are pointing at, in JavaScript you want to assign `this` to a variable, so that you can call the function off of that specific version of `this`. Often referred to as `self` or `that`. Like so:

```
function SectionHandler($appWrap) {
    var self = this;
    self.appWrap = $appWrap;

    self.loading = function() {
       self.appWrap.addClass('section-loading')
           .html("<i class='fa fa-refresh fa-2x fa-spin'></i>");
    }

    self.setError = function($info) {
        self.appWrap.addClass('section-error').html($info);
    }

    self.load = function($section) {
        var $fileCheck = $.get($section).success(function(){
            self.loading();
            self.load($section);
        }).fail(function(){
            self.setError('No se pudo cargar los datos especificados' + 
                        ' desde /[ ' + $section + ' ]\ ;');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, it's because `this` in the code here no longer means the `SectionHandler` but is instead refereeing to `$.get($section).success(function()`. A way to handle this is store `this` in a variable before going into a function:

```
function SectionHandler($appWrap) {
    var self = this;
    ...
    this.load = function($section) {
        var $fileCheck = $.get($section).success(function(){
            self.loading();
            ...
```